# Call the method of Java class which implements runnable after creating its thread object

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, producer-consumer

I have a java class

```
SomeClass implements Runnable
```

Which has a method display().

When I create a thread of this class

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new SomeClass());
```

Now how I can call the display() method using the thread instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will end up calling `start()` on `thread1`.

`SomeClass` will override `run()` method which in turn need to call `display()` method.

This way when you call `start()`, run method of `SomeClass()` object will be invoked and display() method will be executed.

Example:

```
public class SomeClass implements Runnable {
    private List yourArrayList;
    public void run() {
        display();
    }

    public void display() {
        //Your display method implementation.
    }
   public List methodToGetArrayList()
   {
    return  yourArrayList;
   }
}
```

Update:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass()
Thread thread1 = new Thread(sc);
thread1.join();
sc.methodToGetArrayList();
```

NOTE: Example is to illustrate the concept, there may be syntax errors.

If you don't use join(), as Andrew commented, there may be inconsitence in results.

Comment: Run method is called and a loop is executing in it but I am storing all the information during the execution in an ArrayList in the SomeClass I need to get that ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I wanted that exactly.

Comment: @wali: You are welcome. Enjoy coding. If answer helped you don't forget to accept it.

Comment: I am waiting to accept. They need 5 more minutes to confirm that I am not spam :)...

Comment: @wali: No hurry! when it permits.

Comment: This is going to cause access problems. You need to wait for the thread to be completed before accessing the list. It would be better to use an asynchronous approach and pass a callback.

Comment: @Nambari in the same case what is going to be the most suitable way to stop the thread. I am working on Multiple Producer and Multiple Consumer problem and solved it used BlockedQueue. When Queue become empty and producer stop producing products I stuck in the situation that consumers are waiting (deadlock) How I can avoid that. Thanks.

Comment: @wali: Have you looked at these examples http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/ProducerconsumerforJ2SE15usingconcurrent.htm?

Comment: @Wali: If that didn't work, I would suggest post new question with some code.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to call display from your new thread then it needs to be within you run method.

If you want to call it from the calling thread then create a new object, pass this into your new thread and then call display from your falling thread

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
new Thread(sc).start();
sc.display()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I wanted that exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Simple delegation:

```
public class SomeClass implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        display();
    }

    public void display() {
        //...
    }

}
```

Comment: Run method is called and a loop is executing in it but I am storing all the information during the execution in an ArrayList in the SomeClass I need to get that ArrayList.