# Using new Thread(foo).start() in Java. Looking for Best Practices

Tags: java, multithreading, coding-style

In [Call the method of Java class which implements runnable after creating its thread object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370022/call-the-method-of-java-class-which-implements-runnable-after-creating-its-threa) @RNJ proposed launching a Java Thread as

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
new Thread(sc).start();
```

in order to being able to call sc's methods from the current thread.

To me two questions arise from this:

1. How can sc's thread lifecycle methods be called in this construct (like stop())?
2. Is this really a good practice for thread instantiation when one wants to be able to call the remote methods or is there a more elegant/cleaner solution?

Comment: When you say "call the remote method," do you intend to have some service that executes in parallel to the caller?

Comment: 1. since the reference to the newly created thread is not saved, no method can be called on it. 2. 'remote method'? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can't, you need to keep a reference to the newly created Thread, but that is just matter of rearranging the code a little.

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
Thread thread = new Thread(sc);
thread.start();
```

2) In my personal opinion is always cleaner to have something that implements `Runnable` (it implies that can be run, anywhere, and it's just that... something that "runs") than to create something that extends `Thread` and overwrites the run method. If you do that you are implying your SomeClass **is a** Thread (which is a very bold assumption, you probably just want something that can be run and that's it, a thread sounds like a not-nice abstraction, tighlty coupled to an implementation.).

In the very end both solutions are the same, but Runnable one is more elegant... and flexible! If you decide to change your implementation in the future so each of your tasks are not run in a new thread but in a shared Executor or a ThreadPool... you won't need to change anything on your Someclass if it extended Runnable.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
...
...
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
executor.execute(sc);
```

Comment: Of course, it always depends on **what** you are doing. This is just a rule of the thumb.

Comment: What you are talking about is delegation vs. inheritance.  The runnable that you pass to a Thread constructor becomes the thread's _delegate_.   Modern practice favors delegation over inheritance (e.g., _has a_ is a better relationship than _is a_.)  You effectively said, code that uses delegation instead of inheritance often is "more flexible" (a.k.a., less brittle).  It also usually is easier to test.

Comment: Also note:  Inheritance is even less powerful in Java than in some other languages because Java only has single inheritance.  If some class Foo _extends_ Thread, then that limits what you can do with it (i.e., it can't extend any other class).  Making Foo _implement_ Runnable and using it as the delegate of a Thread is less limiting.

Comment: @jameslarge yes, totally. Inheritance is a hard-tightly coupled relationship. However I am not demonizing it, but just stressing that it should be handled with care. Specially in situations like this when by using inheritance you end up missing two totally different concerns or sets of responsibilities into the same object: "to run and do whatever it has to do" and "to be a thread, be able to start, stop be interrupted, etc etc etc"

Comment: Sorry, I only started out to inject the word "delegate" into the conversation, but then somehow, I ended up on a soapbox.